# MVC2 mailto with attachment returned by action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

i have a situation where i need to send an email with attachment using clients Outloook,

```
<% string filePath = "http://localhost/GetPDF";%>
<a href="mailto:?subject=Report&attachment='<%: filePath %>'">Send via outlook</a>
```

the GetPDF action returns a pdf i.e.:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{

    byte[] pdfBytes = null;
    //pdf generation
    ....................

    context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.pdf; size=" + pdfBytes.Length.ToString());
    context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
    context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
    context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
    context.HttpContext.Response.End();
}
```

but unfortunately after the send mail window opens, pdf is not attached =/
can this be fixed ?

Thank You !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to attach files using the mailto: URI scheme.

Comment: Send the email from the server, not the client.

Comment: Thats the problem )
i need to have both options.

Comment: Sending from the client is not and cannot be an option — no matter what your needs are.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the source of the problem, but try using FileContentActionResult instead of playing with the response directly.